# Git deploy repository issue

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have a core code base and a projects directory beneath this to hold project specific code.

```
/Core
/Core/code/*
/projects/name1/*
/projects/name2/*
```

This has been setup as a repository and are currently using it to develop the system.
We have found this to be fantastic as we are able to swop between projects to quickly test for bugs when core code is changed.

The issue now is in deploying the individual projects.
Each project would need to have the Core code as well as its projects directory. But we want to exclude the other project directories from it.

In other words we need to create a clone repo with:

```
/Core
/Core/code
/projects/name2
```

This clone would still pull from the main repo. We just don't want it to be populated with the other project directories.

How do we tell git to ignore merging in those directories when we pull?

I have tried:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged
```

on the directories I want to skip which works when I pull. 
But if I go and create a further clone of this repo all the "untracked" directories are back...

Answer (score 0):

Git isn't designed to work that way.

However, [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) exist just to fit your specific need. I'd suggest splitting each project into its own repo (by forking the existing repo and cleaning up, to preserve history), and Core into its own repo, and include Core into each project as a submodule.